# What is this warning when debugging - Flutter

Tags: flutter

Note: `C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_database-9.1.7\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\database\FirebaseDatabasePlugin.java` uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with `-Xlint:deprecation` for details.
Note: `C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_dynamic_links-4.3.11\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\dynamiclinks\FlutterFirebaseDynamicLinksPlugin.java` uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with `-Xlint:unchecked` for details.

After these red lined messages app is compiling.

But I need to get rid of this warning.

Please give me a solution.